# Bad array new length

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to display a video from a network camera but the program is showing bad array new length when i declare the camera ulr.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int, char**) {
    cv::VideoCapture vcap;
    cv::Mat image;

    // This works on a D-Link CDS-932Lrtsp://<Admin:mmcc2019>@10.5.1.101/

    const std::string videoSt = "http://192.168.226.101:8080/video?x.mjpeg";
    std::cout <<"lenght og the cmera ulr is" <<videoSt.length() << std::endl;

    //open the video stream and make sure it's opened
    if (!vcap.open(videoSt)) {
        std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    for (;;) {
        if (!vcap.read(image)) {
            std::cout << "No frame" << std::endl;
            cv::waitKey();
        }
        cv::imshow("Output Window", image);
        if (cv::waitKey(1) >= 0) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: no mater what string I pass to the variable  "const std::string videoSt" , i get the same error. i.e bad array new length

Comment: Do you see any of your other messages? Have you tried removing any of your video capture code and seeing if you still get the error?

Comment: when i remove the video capture code then there is no error. I can print the length of the url and i can also print it with no error.

Comment: According to the OpenCV documentation the string passed to `vcap.open()` is a filename not a URL. Have you tried the same code using a local file?

Answer (score 5):

I just meet the same problem, it's because I used `opencv_world412.lib` under debug mode; switching to release mode, or using `opencv_world412d.lib` will fix this issue.